# Incompatible Framework version in NuGet Installation

Tags: .net, frameworks, nuget, package, version

I'm trying to install the 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies' Nuget Package in Visual Studio Community 2017.

For some reason, I'm getting this error, and I can't seem to find the solution for this in google.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Could not install package 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.12'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I tried to lower the project's .NetFramework version to 4.5.2, as per the instructions of a course in Udemy.com, but to no avail.

does anybody know how to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [package metadata on fuget.org](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/9.0.2.12), it only lists "net462" after Frameworks. Therefore, you need to update your project to use a TFM that is compatible with net462 (.NET Framework 4.6.2 or higher, but possibly NuGet will restore into some .NET Core projects as well. I don't know much about asset selection fallback), but you're currently using net461.

Answer (score 0):

go to the project properties and change the 'Target Frameowrk 4.5.2. To 4.6.2